# Different permissions for guest and non-guest users in Samba

Tags: permissions, samba, file-permissions, chmod, smb-conf

I am configuring a samba server for file sharing. I was wondering if there is a configuration setting to map different file or directory masks to different users.

I am attempting to allow admin users to have full access to a share while restricting guest users from listing directory contents.

Ive looked through the smb.conf [man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) and found nothing helpful.

Currently my samba share config looks like this:

```
[Public]
   Comment = Pi public share
   Path = /Samba/Public
   Browseable = yes
   Writeable = yes
   create mask = 0666
   directory mask = 1337
   Guest ok = yes
```

This config works perfectly if a guest were to create a new directory but if an admin tries the same he is restricted in this new directory.

I was wondering if there is a way solve this problem in samba, or if necessary, with a filesystem hack or pre/postrun script.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody stumbling across my post in the future I was able to solve this problem by creating 2 samba shares, both mapped to the same location. One share allowing guests. The setup works perfectly for my situation. My configurations look like this:

```
[Public]
   Comment = Public share for guests
   Path = /Samba/Public
   Browseable = yes
   Writeable = yes
   create mask = 0666
   directory mask = 1337
   Guest ok = yes
   Guest only = yes

[AdminPublic]
   Comment = Public share for admins
   Path = /Samba/Public
   Browsable = no
   Writeable = yes
   create mask = 0744
   directory mask = 1733
   Guest ok = no
```